# Rails 5 - Attribute update if relative model's attribute is different

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've created an attribute that is supposed to update a datetime field with the value of a child model's attribute if it's newer (or older based on which field)

```
def update_project_record
    client = Client.find(project.client_id)
    puts client
    project.start_date = self.task_start_date if self.task_start_date < project.start_date 
    project.end_date = self.task_end_date if self.task_end_date > project.end_date
    if client.nearest_project_start.present?
        client.assign_attributes(:nearest_project_start => self.task_start_date, :nearest_project_id => self.project_id) if self.task_start_date < client.nearest_project_start     
    else
        client.assign_attributes(:nearest_project_start => self.task_start_date, :nearest_project_id => self.project_id)
    end
    if client.furthest_project_end.present?
        client.assign_attributes(:furthest_project_end => self.task_end_date, :furthest_project_id => self.project_id) if self.task_end_date > client.furthest_project_end
    else
        client.assign_attributes(:furthest_project_end => self.task_end_date, :furthest_project_id => self.project_id)
    end
    client.save
end
```

It's messy, but it is working within the app.

A `Client` has many `Projects` which has many `Tasks` and a `Client has many Tasks through Projects`

However, when I try to seed the DB I am seeing an output similar to:

```
SDK Enhancement
#<Client:0x007fa89d33bda8>
#<Client:0x007fa89d31a108>
Task 1
#<Client:0x007fa89d2c1580>
#<Client:0x007fa89d2a0880>
Task 3
#<Client:0x007fa89d2488b0>
#<Client:0x007fa89d21bae0>
Task 4
#<Client:0x007fa89d1bfbc8>
#<Client:0x007fa89d19eec8>
Task 5
#<Client:0x007fa89d142e98>
#<Client:0x007fa89d11e0c0>
Task 6
#<Client:0x007fa89d0c1f78>
#<Client:0x007fa89d0a1278>
Task 7
#<Client:0x007fa89d049208>
#<Client:0x007fa89d024430>
Task 8
#<Client:0x007fa89cfcc3c0>
#<Client:0x007fa89cfa3588>
Task 9
#<Client:0x007fa89cf4b478>
#<Client:0x007fa89cf2a5c0>
Task 17
#<Client:0x007fa89ced2438>
#<Client:0x007fa89ceb1670>
Task 28
#<Client:0x007fa89ce59600>
#<Client:0x007fa89ce348a0>
Task 39
```

Which seems like it's pulling the Client but not updating the record? (Unsure how to test this theory).

I then went into the app and make a Client -> Project -> Task as a user would and all records look as if I would expect, but it seems like Seeding ignores this function, but it IS updating the `Project` portion.

**Seed File**

```
task_list = [
  ['Task 1', 'Nothing to add', '2017-09-01', '2018-01-01', 1, 1, 0],  
  ['Task 3', 'Nothing to add', '2017-08-01', '2017-10-01', 1, 2, 1],
  ['Task 4', 'Nothing to add', '2017-06-01', '2017-09-01', 1, 3, 1],
  ['Task 5', 'Nothing to add', '2017-11-01', '2017-12-01', 1, 4, 0],
  ['Task 6', 'Nothing to add', '2017-08-01', '2018-02-01', 1, 5, 0],
  ['Task 7', 'Nothing to add', '2017-08-01', '2017-12-01', 1, 6, 0],
  ['Task 8', 'Nothing to add', '2017-11-01', '2017-12-15', 1, 7, 0],
  ['Task 9', 'Nothing to add', '2017-07-01', '2017-08-15', 1, 1, 0],
  ['Task 17', 'Nothing to add', '2017-04-01', '2017-08-01', 1, 6, 1],
  ['Task 28', 'Nothing to add', '2017-08-01', '2017-10-01', 1, 7, 0],
  ['Task 39', 'Nothing to add', '2018-01-01', '2018-04-01', 1, 1, 1]
]

task_list.each do |name, comment, start, end_date, project, product, completed|
  dproject = Project.find(project)
  dproject.tasks.create!(task_name: name, comment: comment, task_start_date: start, task_end_date: end_date, project_id: project, product: product, completed: completed)
  puts name
end
```

I originally didn't have the project assignment line but I was seeing if perhaps that resolved the MIA Client details.

**Tl;dr**

If a Task is created and has a later `end_date` than the Client's `furthest_project_end` datefield, it should update that field. It is not currently updating. It IS however updating the `project.end_date`

Comment: it is kind of hard to follow, do you have any idea what is not working and maybe you can rephrase your question/problem just with a simplifier version of your code that targets your real issue.

Comment: Where is `update_project_method` located?  It looks like it might be a controller method, and I don't see that you're calling it in the seeding loop..

Comment: @SteveTurczyn It's in the Task model. Tied to an `after_save` and `after_create`